# Removing Negative Elements in a List - Python

Tags: python, for-loop

So, I`m trying to write a function that removes the negative elements of a list without using .remove or .del. Just straight up for loops and while loops. I don`t understand why my code doesn`t work. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

```
def rmNegatives(L):
    subscript = 0
    for num in L:
        if num < 0:
            L = L[:subscript] + L[subscript:]
        subscript += 1
    return L
```

Comment: You're mutating your list as you iterate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A note to your code:

```
L = L[:subscript] + L[subscript:]
```

does not change your list. For example

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> l[:2] + l[2:]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Other mistakes:

```
def rmNegatives(L):
    subscript = 0
    for num in L: # here you run over a list which you mutate
        if num < 0:
            L = L[:subscript] + L[subscript:] # here you do not change the list (see comment above)
        subscript += 1 # you have to do this only in the case, when you did not remove an element from the list
    return L
```

A running code would be:

```
def rmNegatives(L):
    subscript = 0
    for num in list(L):
        if num < 0:
            L = L[:subscript] + L[subscript+1:]
        else:
            subscript += 1
    return L
```

See the solutions of @Aesthete and @sshashank124 for better implementations of your problem...

Answer (score 5):

Why not use list comprehension:

```
new_list = [i for i in old_list if i>=0]
```

#### Examples

```
>>> old_list = [1,4,-2,94,-12,-1,234]
>>> new_list = [i for i in old_list if i>=0]
>>> print new_list
[1,4,94,234]
```

As for your version, you are changing the elements of the list while iterating through it. You should absolutely avoid it until you are ***absolutely*** sure what you are doing.

As you state that this is some sort of exercise with a `while` loop, the following will also work:

```
def rmNegatives(L):
    i = 0
    while i < len(L):
        if L[i]<0:
            del L[i]
        else:
            i+=1
    return L
```

Comment: I have to use the same list. I have to iterate over it.

Comment: You are already creating a new list when you do `L = L[:subscript] + L[subscript:]`. and if you call your function like this: `L = rmNegatives(L)`, then you're creating a new one here too. Are you really sure that you need to keep the *same* object?

Comment: @Fury, But I'm _not_ using `L = L[:subscript] + L[subscript:]`

Comment: @ToxicTechnetium, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You could also use filter, if you so please.

```
L = filter(lambda x: x > 0, L)
```