# remove negative element from nested list and square the list without using loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Input: `testlist = [[1,2,3,-1],2,3,[3,-4,1,3],-1,-3]`

Requirement: 
remove elements less than zero 
then square the elements  without using any loop

output :
`[[1,4,9],4,9,[9,1,9]]`

```
def testlist(f, l):
    def listelement(inside):
        return testlist(f, inside) if type(inside) is list else f(inside)

    return list(map(listelement, l))


def square(x):
    return x * x


def square_list(l):
    return testlist(square, l)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code.

Comment: Please read about [ask]. We expect to see some effort of actually solving your own problem and the question should be focused on a specific coding task, rather than asking for a complete program... For example: `How to remove negative elements from a list` **OR** `how to square all elements of a list`

Comment: Again, please read the [ask] article and take the [tour]. Any information should be [edit]ed to your question, not in the comments

Comment: Thanks for how to ask link, really sorry as i am very new to stackoverflow. appriciate link.

Comment: Hi Rashid, i have inseted the code in description, i am able to sqare the elements for nested list . negative elements removal form nested list is where i need help.. thanks

Comment: Can't mark two duplicates, but here is how to [square a nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45449304/square-of-numbers-in-nested-list-python-3) and here is how to [remove negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976568/removing-negative-elements-in-a-list-python)

Comment: Thanks Tomerikoo for the links but  I am trying to remove negative numbers  without loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could think about the problem recursively:

1. If the list is empty, return an empty ist
2. If it isn't, for the first item of the list:

   1. If it's a negative number, omit it
   2. If it's a non-negative number, square it
   3. If it's a list, apply the function on it.
3. Return a list that's a concatenation of the element from #1 and the function applied to the rest of the list.

Or, in python:

```py
def func(l):
    if len(l) == 0:
        return []

    item = l[0]
    if isinstance(item, list):
        result = [func(item)]
    elif item >= 0:
        result = [item**2]
    else:
        result = []

    return result + func(l[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having two separate functions, you can do the squaring and the checking for positive in the same function.

To handle not looping we can use recursion. Since we are already using recursion, we can handle lists with the same recursive function.

```
test_list = [[1,2,3,-1],2,3,[3,-4,1,3],-1,-3]


def positive_square_list(lst, index):
    if index < len(lst):
        if type(lst[index]) == list:
            positive_square_list(lst[index], 0)
            index += 1

        if lst[index] < 0:
            lst.pop(index)
            index -= 1
            if index == len(lst):
                return lst
            else:
                return positive_square_list(lst, index+1)

        lst[index] = lst[index] ** 2
        return positive_square_list(lst, index+1)

    return lst



output = positive_square_list(test_list, 0)
```

The variable output will have the values: `[[1,4,9],4,9,[9,1,9]]`